# Authenticate public-key which is coming from a database

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, chat

I wrote a small Chat application, where users can write each other messages:

- On first Login, a user will generate a public/private keypair, derived from the users password.
- The public-key will be sent to the server (database).
- If a user (A) wants to write user (B) a message, user A encrypts the message with the public key of user B and sends it to the server (and the server will send it then to user B).

But what, if somebody with database-access will change the public-key of user B in the database? Then the attacker can read all messages.

Is it somehow possible to authenticate the public key in the database and make sure, it was not changed and it 100% belongs to user B?

Comment: This may be better asked at http://security.stackexchange.com. Interesting question, how to ensure the system is secure even if an attacker has infiltrated the server… I don't think there really is an answer, besides *not trusting the server* and ensuring the private key is exchanged securely initially, then storing it client side.

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to protect against the scenario where an attacker has control over the server and the server cannot be trusted. Since you can't trust *any* information by the server, you cannot use it directly in any form of verification either. The server can only be relegated to being a dumb transport, and the verification needs to happen directly against the other peer.

Being able to exchange the key out-of-band would help a lot here, meaning you can somehow facilitate a direct peer-to-peer exchange of the key. Since it is difficult to trust the identity of a random remote peer over the general internet, you'd need to employ a strategy like [Threema](https://threema.ch): you can get any remote peer's public key anonymously, but your relationship to this peer is not verified then. Only if you're able to meet in person and exchange/verify keys by physically scanning each others QR codes is the key trustworthy.

To facilitate any sort of key exchange with a remote peer via an untrustworthy server, you'd basically need to implement a Diffie-Hellman key exchange; the server can facilitate the communication, but will have no visibility into what data is being exchanged. This will have to happen with both peers being online at the same time (or it's a very slow offline back-and-forth), so may be somewhat problematic in practice depending on your use case.

Comment: Out-of-band public key verification is necessary here, but it's not fully trustworthy, because the software itself may already be compromised. We need reproducible open-source builds for that.